# can I put javascript inside the brackets of a script tag with src on it?

Tags: javascript, php

I use these variables assigned by PHP in my linked javascript file below. Just wondering if its ok to do this:

```
<script src="js/settings.js">
var chores = <?php if ($chores == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
var contacts = <?php if ($contacts == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
var gyms = <?php if ($gyms == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
var meetings = <?php if ($meetings == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
var spirituals = <?php if ($spirituals == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
</script>
```

Or should I do this:

```
<script>
    var chores = <?php if ($chores == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
    var contacts = <?php if ($contacts == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
    var gyms = <?php if ($gyms == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
    var meetings = <?php if ($meetings == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
    var spirituals = <?php if ($spirituals == 0) echo "false"; else echo "true"; ?>;
</script>
<script src="js/settings.js"></script>
```

Both seem to work fine.  I don't know why I'm nervous about the top one.

Comment: I wouldn't use that first possibility as it makes both scripts (one in file and second written in the html) less distinguishable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the js file (js/settings.js) uses the variables assigned in the document then you should include the javascript file **after** the variables have been assigned otherwise you're likely to get 'undefined' error.

If `js/settings.js` use something like `$(document).ready(...` in which the variables are used after the document is loaded then either way would be fine.

Ideally, in my opinion you should always include the script files after

Comment: You were right, the first one didn't actually work like I originally thought.  The second is the correct way. Thanks!